# Is there a way to detect the order of a module's globals() in python?

Tags: python, reflection, global-variables

Some globals are used in a python module:

```
ImFirst = 1  
ImSecond = 2  
AndImThird = "three"
```

globals() gives a dict of those names and values, but unfortunately it is not an OrderedDict (obviously, since globals() predates the collections module).

Is there a way to get the order in which the global names appear in the module?

Comment: Is there's any specific reason for doing this?

Comment: Not for simple variables unless you parse the source yourself. For code objects (basically, functions) you can reconstruct the ordering from the embedded line numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: For CPython `sys._getframe()` lets you inspect the currently executing `frame.f_code`, or you can `compile` the source, or load the code from a pyc with `marshal`, but unutbu's solution is probably simpler.

Comment: @eryksun: decoding `co_lnotab` is going to be fun.. the tokenize approach is much cleaner.

Comment: [`dis.findlinestarts`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis#dis.findlinestarts) and the list `dis.opname` can help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to eryksun's comment above, I dived into the 'attributes tree' of sys._getframe(),
and apparently all the global names, by order of appearance in code, exist in:

```
sys._getframe().f_code.co_names
```

It also includes variables that are undefined, but joining this info with globals() does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [tokenize.generate_tokens](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.generate_tokens) to collect data on the order in which token names appear.

For example, if you save this file as `/tmp/test.py` and run
`python /tmp/test.py`, it will read its own code and report the order the globals appear:

```
import tokenize
import io
import token
import collections
import itertools

class Token(collections.namedtuple('Token', 'toknum tokval start end line')):
    @property
    def tokname(self):
        return token.tok_name[self.toknum]

ImFirst = 1  
ImSecond = 2  
AndImThird = "three"
if ImSecond:
    ImFourth = 4.0

seen = set()
order = []
with open('/tmp/test.py', 'r') as f:
    for tok in itertools.starmap(Token, tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline)):
        if tok.tokname == 'NAME' and tok.tokval not in seen:
            seen.add(tok.tokval)
            order.append(tok.tokval)

order = [name for name in order if name in globals()]
print(order)
```

yields

```
['tokenize', 'io', 'token', 'collections', 'itertools', 'Token', 'ImFirst', 'ImSecond', 'AndImThird', 'ImFourth', 'seen', 'order', 'f', 'tok', 'name']
```